# issue in Bulk load data conversion e

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I am uploading data from file using BULK INSERT,

here is my snippet,

```
BULK INSERT Table_Name  FROM path WITH (FIRSTROW = 2,FIELDTERMINATOR='|',ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
```

here is my input file data,

```
col1|col2|col3
a|b|a.
a|c|h
```

while executing I got error as follows,

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 2 column 3 (col3). (4863) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 2, column 3 (col3). (4863)')
```

Please help me to fix this

Comment: Given you're trying to invoke this from Python, try replacing `ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'` with `ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'`.

Comment: it is giving same error